# hapijs - serve static files from directory handler with variable path name

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to do something like this in my routes file using hapijs + [inert plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/inert#the-directory-handler)

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/l/{path*}',
  handler: {
    directory: {
      path: (req) => {
        const defaultDir = '/public';
        return getHostInfo(req.headers.host).then((d) => {
          if (!d || !d.directory) return defaultDir;
          return d.directory;
        }).catch((e) => {
          return defaultDir;
        });
      }
    }
  }
},
```

`path` parameter expects a string, array or function which returns a string or array...in my case, my function returns a promise...so it doesn't work.
I tried adding `hapi-as-promised` package which modifies `reply` function to support `then` method but did't work.

Basically I want to serve static assets from one directory or another depending on the host header value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only thing i have in my mind is this hack. First, you have to make an extension point to make your async stuff:

```
server.ext({
    type: `onPreHandler`,
    method: (request, reply) => {
        const defaultDir = '/public';
        return getHostInfo(request.headers.host).then((d) => {
            if (!d || !d.directory) {
                request.app.dirPath = defaultDir;
                return;
            }
            request.app.dirPath = d.directory;
        }).catch((e) => {
            request.app.dirPath = defaultDir;
        }).then(() => {
            return reply.continue();
        });
    }
});
```

And then the route:

```
{
    method: `get`,
    path: `/l/{path*}`,
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: (request) => {
                return request.app.dirPath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how right is this way, but i tested and it worked. So i hope this helps. And i gotta notice, using node to server files on production isn't a common way by some reason.

Comment: Finally I used reply.file playing with the url parameter, I guess it saves some db queries vs using the pre handler approach but of course your solution is valid. I know this isn't the best way, I just had a very weird requirement, received a zip file with html's and assets, and they wanted to replace a react app index route by custom landing pages out of the project depending on the subdomain...I don't like the solution (neither the requirement) but will think on a better approach right after have this working in order to gain time.
Please warn me if your approach might be better.

Comment: @Polak yea, seems like a more sophisticated way to make that :)

Comment: Still, if someone will use the way i wrote, don't make an extension, use prerequisites instead.